# HTML - SQL query for registering new accounts

Tags: php, html, registration

I'm writing a query so that whatever is entered into the form is input into the database. This is my code so far, I think its a problem with the actual query because I'm not entirely sure how to enter variables into a SQL query, if anyone can help me out that would be sound :)

Registration submit PHP

```
    <font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $user = $_POST['registerusername'];

    $pass = $_POST['registerpassword'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, DateofBirth, Username, Password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$dob', '$user', '$pass')";



}
```

Registration Form PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">
<a href="homepage.php" title="back to home">HOME</a>
</font>
    <head>

        <style>
            body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css" />
    </head>
    <body> 
    <center>
    <div id="registrationform" style="font-family: 'ClearSans-Thin'; color: lightgray">


        Please enter your registration details<br /><br />

        <form method="post" action="registrationsubmit.php">
            First Name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
            <br />
            Last Name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
            <br />
            Email:<br />
            <input type="text" name="email" />
            <br />
            Date of Birth:<br />
            <input type="date" name="dob" />
            <br />
            Username:<br />
            <input type="text" name="registerusername" />
            <br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="text" name="registerpassword" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="regsubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </center>
</div>



        </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

Went onto PHPmyadmin and I inserted some information and it showed the SQL, which was:

```
INSERT INTO `c3438525`.`Users` (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `DateofBirth`, `Username`, `Password`) VALUES (NULL, 'Matt', 'Murphy', 'Matt.murphy@gmail.com', '1993-11-14', 'Admin', 'Admin');
```

So basically how would I replace the information with variables?

Comment: what do you use in connection.php? mysql, mysqli, pdo?

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'c3438525') or exit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a prepared statement to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, DateofBirth, Username, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $firstname,$lastname,$email,$dob,$user,$pass);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die('Error when inserting:'.mysqli_error($connection));
 }else{
die('Error when preparing '.mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

And **never ever** try to insert **pure user data**!
For sanitizing it use `$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);`
You have some `FILTER_SANITIZE` constants in PHP, so use them : )
Find them at : http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: I'm not, but you are welcome. Have a nice programming night (its quite dark in Europe) : )

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parameterized query to pass parameters into your SQL statement. The alternative, of building up a SQL statement by creating a string with the parameters in place leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Something like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, DateofBirth, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $dob, $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a parametrised query and bind the parameters.  Since you have chosen the procedural style, you'll need something along these lines:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, DateofBirth, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $dob, $user, $pass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

For more information, please see:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Please be sure to **validate** the data before you insert it into the database.  I cannot stress how important that is.  **Never** accept tainted input data directly into your application.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an integer field you cant store it like that `12-34-5678` for this variable you need a varchar or text field

Comment: Is this an answer to his question?  How do you know how hes storing his data? It works, as its stated above, next to phpmyadmin man

Comment: wtf?!? no its an answer to santa clause.. isnt it possible that he is using an integer field to store NOT INTEGER values? of course some beginners will do that (including me a few years ago) his question suggested that hes a real beginner so why do you "man" think that couldnt be a possible problem? it could be a very big problem. try and you will recognize..

Comment: Hey, calm down. He just tried inserting that data into database, and it succeded. Read the `UPDATE` part :)  He just dont know how to properly insert it in php

Comment: why your 1 comment is not written that way?

Comment: Good question, but too good for StackOverflow :P It contains 0 aggresion, but, yes, second is chilling xD

Comment: i will think twice too next time :D

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow xd and have a nice day :P